# Android FusedLocationproviderApi requestLocationUpdates not running pendingIntent in deep sleep mode

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi

I'm using [requestLocationUpdates](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

```
GoogleApiClient client; 
LocationRequest request; 
PendingIntent callbackIntent;
```

From `FusedLocationProviderApi`. It is working correctly and frequently when screen is ON.

However it doesn't call the PendingIntent when the device goes into to sleep mode. How can I keep getting updates in sleep mode?

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to get the locations in deep sleep mode ?
Even I am facing the same issue.
I observed I received the locations (that were updated during deep sleep mode) after the device woke up but with current timestamp (time after wokeup).
I have made my Application class as Listener for my own reasons. And I am not pretty sure if the reason for onLocationChanged() not hit is if the component was not running in deep sleep mode..in my case it is Application.

I have ONE SOLTUION - you can have ALarmManager which fires at regular intervals and you acquir partial_wakelock that wakes the CPU up and call getLastKnownLocation() and release the wakelock. This does not seem to be a suitable solution for my case as I want locations based on Displacement.

**EDIT**
The working solution is [http in deep sleep mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33923072/3209739). Though question is irrelevant, context is same. Receiving locations this way should also work.