# How to use CPU to perform any operation in Deep Sleep mode

Tags: android, android-asynctask, alarmmanager, intentservice, sleep-mode

I'm new in `android`. I struggle with my application approximately 3 weeks. I need sent and receive packets in normal mode and `sleep mode`. `My app` must exchange data a 5 seconds. I tried using `alarmmanager` but on android 5 it's not works. On `android` 5 an interval changes it on 60 seconds. Such a solution makes the battery wears out quickly. When I use normal asynctask, not `IntentService`, then it works only when screen is `ON` and `app` is visible. When app is hidden or I click power `OFF` then exchange data stops working. What is the best solutions?

Comment: You must use a Service for this. and yes this will quickly drain the battery

Comment: AlarmManager is the way to go. You can customize it to whatever interval you want. It doesn't have to be 60 seconds...

Comment: When I use a Service then the application works only when the screen is turned on and the application is visible. I use also alarmmanager with IntentService but on android 5 a interval changes on 60 seconds.

Comment: @SeaDog - See my answer below.

Comment: @SeaDog, could you manage to implement it ?

Comment: @SeaDog can you delete your answer as it is not actually an answer.

Comment: @cgr, I removed my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even RTC_WAKEUP doesn't help most of the times.

**Solution that worked for my app when device in deep sleep mode:**
Use [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) combined with AlarmManager.

Service is started by startWakefulService() and when it is finished, it releases the wake lock by calling completeWakefulIntent(intent). So the device will be allowed to go back to sleep.

I'm not adding any code. Search for examples on how to use WakefulBroadcastReceiver with AlarmManager. Even WakefulBroadcastReceiver doc has some template code.

Also reduce the frequency of alarm so you can avoid draining so much battery.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96317/discussion-on-answer-by-cgr-how-to-use-http-in-sleep-mode).

Comment: tutorial link is broken

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AlarmManager` class to wake up the device at a particular time, then fire off an operation at whatever interval you'd like. Code [from the docs found here](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html):

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 20 minutes.
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
1000 * 60 * 20, alarmIntent);
```

Notice the last line of this block. You can use the method `setRepeating()` to set whatever interval you'd like.

Comment: is it true what @cgr wrote?

Comment: @drschultz, Yes. We have used very recently in our app and it works even in deep sleep mode. We don't have the latest version yet in play store but will be available soon so you can verify it for yourself.