# Is it possible to execute network tasks in onTaskRemoved?

Tags: android, android-service

I need when my app completely close (clear from backgrond) post my request to server and when got response service stop from working , this is my Service class :

```
public class OnClearFromRecentService extends Service {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("ClearFromRecentService", "Service Started");

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("ClearFromRecentService", "Service Destroyed");

    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {

        Log.e("ClearFromRecentService", "END");

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(App.baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

        String authorization = prefs.getString("token_type","")+" "+prefs.getString("access_token","");

        Call<JsonArray> response = requestInterface.AppOff(ChatList.offline_user,authorization);

        response.enqueue(new Callback<JsonArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonArray> call, retrofit2.Response<JsonArray> response) {

                String asd = "asd";



                stopSelf();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonArray> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.d(t.getLocalizedMessage(),"failed");

                stopSelf();

            }
        });


    }
```

definition in manifest :

```
 <service android:name="com.iranMobleh.OnClearFromRecentService" android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

and start service from MainActivity like below:

```
 startService(new Intent(this, OnClearFromRecentService.class));
```

seem this code true but problem is when app closed it can't wait for retrofit response

Answer (score 3):

First of all if you set `android:stopWithTask="false"` then `onTaskRemoved` will not be called. So set it to `android:stopWithTask="true"`. See **[Service Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service)**.

Now we move to the solution. You have to put your webservice call into a new Service/Job. and start that service/job by an `AlarmManager`, or `WorkManager` or `EvernoteJobs` or `JobScheduler` when `onTaskRemoved` is called.

Instead of writing same thing again. I found two good answer perfectly fit for you requirement. **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34223274/6891563)** & **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43760343/6891563)**.

Just one change in above answers. I think EvernoteJobs or WorkManager would be better than AlarmManager.

It is easy to implement.

```
public class DemoSyncJob extends Job {

    public static final String TAG = "job_demo_tag";

    @Override
    @NonNull
    protected Result onRunJob(Params params) {
        // run api call here
        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }

   public static void runJobImmediately() {
    int jobId = new JobRequest.Builder(DemoSyncJob.TAG)
            .startNow()
            .build()
            .schedule();
    }
}
```

Visit **[Evernote-jobs](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)** page for integrating.

**Update**

You have to make your project compatible with library. Here is the versions that library uses. So make sure you are using minimum these versions.

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = compileSdkVersion
    minSdkVersion = 14

    buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'

    supportLibVersion = '26.1.0'
}
```

Comment: how can i download this ? cause i try so many time and sees have trouble with download library , are you test it before ? or just give me explain ?

Comment: You seem new to Android, bro, you don't need to download it.

Comment: You simply add `implementation 'com.evernote:android-job:1.2.6'` to your `build.gradle` & Sync project. by adding like dependency, your project will add  itautomatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use WorkManager to run a worker class in the background.

Or use Evernote's android-job.

Link for evernote android-job library: https://github.com/evernote/android-job

Answer (score 0):

Better can u try with `onDestroy` method in the service class, because if the app is force closed then `onTaskRemoved` method not called for sometimes so I recommend to go with `onDestroy` method in service class and also,

you can use Intent Service for achieving your Goal, use that service in `onDestroy()`

you can have a look at following example.

http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android