# Retrieve realtime database values inside Firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Actually I want to show users online/offline status. I read https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence and implemented `onDiscount()` to update Realtime Database that `isOnline = false` on discount but the problem is this data does not update inside `Firestore` when the user is discount.

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();


        myRef.child(IS_ONLINE).setValue(true);
        myRef.child(IS_ONLINE).onDisconnect().setValue(false);

        myRef.child("isOnline").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                status = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
                user.put("isOnline", status);
                doctRef.set(user);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


}
```

Comment: Have you solve the problem?

Comment: Not! actually, in order to retrieve data from realtime to firestore i used background services but the problem is where to call those services. IF I call those services in `onDestroy()`  then they won't work .. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a service to call this method, you can try like this. Once the apps is really removed from the background, this service will trigger.

```
public class ClosingService extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        // Handle application closing
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(getString(R.string.USER));
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) { databaseReference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child(getString(R.string.sedang_online)).setValue(false);
        databaseReference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child(getString(R.string.lastSeen)).setValue(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    // Destroy the service
    stopSelf();
}
}
```

After that, this service is called when the apps is started. For example, at Splashscreen activity.

```
    //Start closing service
    final Intent stickyService = new Intent(this, ClosingService.class);
    startService(stickyService);
```

And don't forget to create the service at androidmanifest.

```
   <service
        android:name=".u.ClosingService"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

Comment: Yes its working but not at all.. Firestore is not updating please take a look at this gist link: https://gist.github.com/Shoaibpython/c1f85b8589622046c89f49806c817e30

Comment: @ShoaibK. did it trigger onFailure?

Comment: No, nothing except first `logd`

Comment: what do you think about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815145/is-it-possible-to-execute-network-tasks-in-ontaskremoved

Comment: I think i should use network call on another thread.... lemme try

Comment: another way is, check if there is connection or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220773/discussion-between-shoaib-k-and-ticherhaz).