# Kotlin Start worker when onTaskRemoved

Tags: android, kotlin, service, android-workmanager

I have a service which gets called when the app is getting removed/closed.
The service will start a OneTimeWorkRequest.
Somehow the Workmanager will never start when onTaskRemoved is called.

Is there a way to make sure that when the app is killed the Workmanager gets to work?

This is my code:
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".OnClearFromRecentService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

OnClearFromRecentService.kt

```
class OnClearFromRecentService : Service() {

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d("log", "Service Started")
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.d("log", "Service Destroyed")
    }

    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
        Log.d("log", "END")

        val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<BackgroundTask>()
            .addTag("oneTime")
            .build()
        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(request)
        
        stopSelf()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem as you that the worker is not executed and started experimenting. I found the following workaround, which simply has `Thread.sleep()` after the code. I suspect that the `WorkManager` needs additional time to schedule the request before the service is killed. From my understanding, after a work request is scheduled, it is guaranteed to execute independent of the app`s state

I tested it multiple times and it always worked. One downside is that it usually takes ~30 seconds until the worker is executed. It seems that it takes some time because it is executed in a new process.

```
    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Constraints constraint = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build();

        WorkRequest workRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest
                .Builder(ServiceKilledJob.class)
                .setConstraints(constraint)
                .build();

        workManager.enqueue(workRequest);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

P.S.: Code is in Java not Kotlin, but I think the workaround should work either way.

Additional note: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51815645/7947994) the author states that `onTaskRemoved` is not always called if `android:stopWithTask` is set to `false`. Therefore I suggest setting it `true`.