# Is there a good solution to restart service after the app is killed?

Tags: android, android-service, huawei-mobile-services

I'm developing an alarm clock application, and I find that alarms will be deleted when the app get killed. I am wondering is there a good solution to fix  that problem?

I tried return "START_STICKY" in service, it works when I test on simulators, but it doesn't work on Huawei device.
And I also tried other things, they also don't work.
When app is killed
1. won't get any broadcast.
2. JobScheduler won't work.
3. all services will get killed.
4. all processes of the app will get killed.
...

I simply want the alarms work even if the app gets killed. So can you help me or give me some advice?

Comment: check this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222943/how-to-restart-service-after-the-app-is-killed-from-recent-tasks

Comment: @KaranMer I tried setting an alarm in "onTaskRemoved", the alarm would be deleted after the app got killed, so it doesn't work.