# How to run Background Service continuously after Activity is destroyed and screen locked

Tags: java, android

I Want to run background service for give me location of user but when I destroy or lock mobile screen, service are killed, it shows nothing. I hope any one had idea about it. please Share.

Sensor Service

Comment: you need foreground service for that

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    ... 
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Did you try `START_STICKY`?

Comment: Yes   @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        Log.i("START", "onStartCommand!");
        startTimer(context);
        return START_STICKY;
   
    } and in startTimer i set timing and call webservice for insert location

Comment: START_STICKY has nothing to do with this problem

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko but service are not run in background after destory and data were not punch in service. :(

Comment: @AakarshRai that's right, and as I said - `START_STICKY has nothing to do with this problem`

Comment: please check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222943/how-to-restart-service-after-the-app-is-killed-from-recent-tasks/34223274)

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko But Couldn't get where is problem used all relevant code regarding this...

Comment: @tadev I am taking location gps provider it give me lat long but problem is arise service doesn't insert values in Server.