# How to prevent the foreground service is killed by mobile cleaner

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-service, mobile-application

I had create a foreground  application in Android 12 that is working fine when tha app is remove from recent task. when I had using my mobile cleaner the foreground service also killed.

How to prevent the foreground service killed by mobile cleaner

Comment: People use these kinds of ridiculous apps because they *want* to force all apps to close. Not much you can do about that except try to educate customers about why these apps make their phones perform worse, not better.

Comment: Yeah the best you can do is try to warn people if your app is something that could be affected by this stuff (it's usually a problem when the app's supposed to run in the background). It's not just cleaner/"green" apps, some manufacturers heavily restrict what apps can do on their devices, and you need to explicitly opt apps out of these restrictions. https://dontkillmyapp.com is a typical resource devs point users to, but that's not about cleaner apps. Maybe you can detect if your app was killed (didn't complete properly) and display a warning / info links next time they open it?

Comment: The issue looks like a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222943/how-to-restart-service-after-the-app-is-killed-from-recent-tasks