# Running a service to monitor incoming calls programmatically , even when phone screen is locked

Tags: android, android-service, android-wake-lock

I made an app which monitor incoming calls for some purpose. The app makes use of a service which in turn uses a PhoneStateListener to monitor incoming calls. *My app requirement is for the incoming call monitoring behaviour to execute even when app is not running and screen is locked conditions.*

The complexity starts when the phone screen is locked and the app is not running. I still need it to monitor incoming phone calls. For this, I decided to use a **PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK** to keep the CPU running even when phone is locked.

App works in all cases after I did this, but using PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK indefinitely like this is known to affect battery life.

I read somewhere that **AlarmManager** might be an alternative. But AlarmManager is used to trigger at **specific time intervals**, but I need the service to work when I get an incoming call, but that happens *randomly*.

What can I do to make the app more battery efficient without affecting functionality?

Comment: Can you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/15564021/3209739 and instead of normal broadcast receiver use WakefulBroadcastReceiver. Follow http://stackoverflow.com/a/33923072/3209739 for detail on how to use wakeful.

Comment: @cgr : I have already got the call detection working, my only problem is potential battery drain. The wakefulbroadcast receiver is used to start and stop a service while holding the wakelock. But my problem is that I need the service to keep running in the background because incoming calls can occur anytime, regardless of phone state (screen-off,screen-on,reboot,app-running,app-not-running). Thereby, I would be holding the partial wake lock indefinitely.